# is it possible to use "has_perm" within a CASE queryset in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to add an additional field to my queryset related to a specific permission, is it possible to use "has_perm" within a CASE?

```
var_group = Group.objects.all().annotate(mypermission=Case(
When(self.has_perm('app.mypermission'), then=Value(True)),
default=Value(False),
output_field=BooleanField(),
))
```

The error is:

> global name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is not defined. The `self` that you used in the `annotate` is not the `Group` object. The queryset is for making SQL queries. The `has_perm` is not a part of query building. It is an `Group` object method.

So, the answer is yes.

```
var_group = Group.objects.all().annotate(mypermission=Case(
When(permissions__codename='app.permission', then=Value(True)),
default=Value(False),
output_field=BooleanField(),
))
```

There is another solution. I suggest to query the all `Group` object, then iterate it one by one to annotate it.

```
var_group = Group.objects.all()

for group in var_group:
    if group.permissions.filter(codename='app.permission').exists():
        group.mypermission = True
    else:
        group.mypermission = False
```

Comment: That is a good idea. I just noticed the Group does not have the method "has_perm", that is only related to the User  **'Group' object has no attribute 'has_perm'**. Any idea to use that method for the Group?

Comment: Ahhh you used the Django Group model https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#group-model. It has no `has_perm` method. I will update the answer.

Comment: The second option is perfect: just (codename='app.permission') does not work, I used (codename='permission')